# quotient of an object

Tags: category-theory, epimorphisms

In category theory
What from these 2 things is called **quotient**:

1. epi

or rather

2. split epi

Whats the difference of a usage of these 2.

Comment: Well, perhaps *regular epi* would do it best in general: it's by definition the coequalizer of a pair of arrows, where pairs of arrows models binary relations, and coequalizer would model the quotient of the generated equivalence relation.

Comment: Technically, neither. A quotient is an equivalence class of epis. A single epi may represent a quotient. Once can place various further conditions on the epis.

Answer (score 1):

Usually *epis* (or, as Ittay Weiss comments, equivalence classes of epis) are called *quotient objects*.

However, in my opinion this is inadequate as a general approach. For example, in the category $\mathbf{Top}$ of topological spaces and continuous maps the epis are nothing else than the continuous surjections. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism. But a quotient object in $\mathbf{Top}$ should be a *[quotient map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology))* which is much more restrictive than being an epi. In fact, the quotient topology on $Y$ is uniquely determined by the space $X$ and the (surjective) function $p$. If $p$ is only required to be an epi, then there are many topologies on the set $Y$ making $p$ continuous.

The dual concept is that of a *subobject*. Usually these are understood to be monos, but again this is problematic. See my answer to [Attempt to define the notion of subobjects](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4198693).